# History of the IP address

Tags: ip-address, history

When and why did networks start using IP addresses? Who were the people that came up with this idea? Did they write some article or publication about their intent or why they couldn't use MAC addresses?

Which networks were first connected together using IP address as an addressing mechanism (because MAC addresses couldn't be used anymore) and which companies or institutions were involved in the beginning of using IP addresses?

Comment: And are you sure on Wikipedia there isn't the info you need? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_model

Comment: Ancestors? It hasn't been that long...this might be better suited at StackOverflow

Comment: @Lohoris I was reading [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) on Wikipedia. [TCP/IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_model) protocol is closely relating topic. Are you sure there is the information? Maybe you can find it when you read this article and and click on lot of other links, but it's lot of uncertain searching already.

Comment: @MichaelF You are right. Is there a better word?

Comment: @Lohoris That article just says "The 1970s" in the header; The information I found below seems to indicate that 1978 was when the IP protocol was split from TCP, though I'm sure there was some equivalent before that.

Comment: I'd like to post the question back to historySE where it belongs. I've already written to moderators. It seems they will let it closed instead of moving it to correct place as it was.

Comment: xralf this is more a technical question than a History question, it's fit is better here for what you are asking rather than in the History site.

Comment: @MichaelF I know the atmosphere here quite good :-) , that's because I supposed historySE will be more suitable. But I'm positively surprised they haven't closed it here yet.

Comment: @MichaelF You see, it's closed. On historySE there is a tag `technology`. It belongs under the tag `technology`. It's pure historical question.

Comment: @xralf, it'snot a historical question if you have a way to frame it such then you are free to try again.

Comment: @MichaelF I have another opinion on this. Not only wars and politics is history. You have history of science, history of technology, history of religion, history of physics...

Comment: Re: MAC (Ethernet). Obviously if you use Eth address you can communicate with other Eth addresses, but you cannot communicate with TokenRing address or with ATM address. If you use IP address you can communicate with other IP addresses (even if you have Eth and they have ATM).

Comment: @kubanczyk This is good reason. Maybe there were more reasons.

Comment: @kubanczyk OK, I think I can accept Canageek answer and your comment is also very helpful.

Comment: It is reasonable to assume that the concept of IP address was conceived along with the development of the Internet Protocol (TCP/IP).The research for the IP suite of protocols started in the late 1960s, and the first publication on TCP was released in 1974 by Vinton Cerf and Robert E. Kahn in 1974. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite#History.

The ARPANET, which is the predecessor of the Internet, began using IP addressing in 1983. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ars Technica has had several articles talking about the history of the internet: [This one](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/news/2011/03/the-essence-of-the-net.ars/2) mostly focuses on TCP, but it also talks about the addition of IP to the TCP/IP stack. It is taken from a longer book, Johnny Ryan's A History of the Internet and the Digital Future, so you might be interested in looking that up.

Specifically:

> TCP was also heterogeneous by nature. It was designed so that machines
>   on different networks using different technologies could seamlessly
>   communicate as though they were on the same network. Various networks
>   were bridged by so-called "gateway" machines that maintained routing
>   tables with the addresses of computers on their own local networks.
>   TCP underwent several revisions, and following a meeting in January
>   1978 between Cerf and two researchers, Jon Postel and Danny Cohen, at
>   the University of South California, it was split into two parts to
>   streamline the functions of the gateway computers. TCP would handle
>   communication between computers and an additional Internet Protocol
>   (IP) handled internetwork connections between networks. The
>   combination of TCP and IP would avoid the gateway computers from
>   duplicating functions already performed by host computers within local
>   networks.

Would seem to indicate that January 1978 was the point at which the protocol was written, with IP addresses seeing use in various networks shortly thereafter.

Comment: Thank you for great tip. I will try to borrow that book.